# Laravel Blade - How to make checkbox stay checked after submit

Tags: html, laravel, checkbox, laravel-blade

I want to create a feature to filter data. I use the checkbox to do this.
But I want when the checkbox is selected and then the user submits to filter the data, the previously selected checkbox remains selected.

i tried to do it like this but it didn't work

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ac" name="ac" value="ac" @if(old('ac')) checked @endif>
```

my form method to submit this is GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`old()` helper function is only for saved flash session data. Without saved it on flash session you can not retrieve it. An example to save flash data for `old()` function

```
request()->flashOnly(['ac']);
```

or

```
return redirect('form')->withInput();
```

If you use GET method and no redirection after submit you can do it using `request()` helper function. Like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ac" name="ac" value="ac" @if(request()->ac) checked @endif>
```

Comment: how about select option ? i tried the same way, but not work

Answer (score 0):

For the submitting form using POST method with multiple checkboxes,

```
@foreach ($categories as $index => $category)
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" 
           value="{{ $category->id }}" 
           {{ (is_array(old('type')) && in_array($index + 1, old('type'))) ? 'checked' : '' }}
           class="form-check-input @error('type') is-invalid @enderror"
           id="type_{{$category->id}}">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="type_{{$category->id}}">
           {{ $category->name }}
    </label>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked form me:

```
 <input name="mail" type="hidden" value="0" >
 <input  name="mail" type="checkbox" value="1"@if(old('mail')) checked @endif>
```

controller:

```
          $request->validate([
            'mail' => 'required',
        ]);

        Contact::create($request->all());
```